# WKWebview allowsLinkPreview to false breaks text selection

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, 3dtouch, ios13.4

We have an app that uses WKWebview, but sets `allowsLinkPreview` to `false` because we don't want link preview behavior.  It seems that starting with iOS 13.4, on devices that *don't* have 3D touch functionality (older devices and newer iphone models), setting `allowsLinkPreview` to false *also* disables all text selection in the page!  For our app, text selection is critically important.

I came up with this theory reading between the lines [in the documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415000-allowslinkpreview)

> In iOS this property is available on devices that support 3D Touch.
>
> On devices running iOS 13 and later, people can use the touch and hold gesture to open a context menu, regardless of whether the device supports 3D Touch. On 3D Touch devices, the gesture can reveal the context menu more quickly.

It seems like a bug that disabling link preview disables *all* press and hold gestures in the webview.

The only workaround I've been able to come up with is to set `allowsLinkPreview` to `true`, and then disabling the context menu via [the WKUIDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/3335220-webview).  This disables the popup for clicked links, but does not disable the popup for clicked images.  And, it still allows users to drag-drop the link into a split screen view in safari, which we do not want.

Any suggestions for how to completely disable link preview/context menu/drag-drop behavior while still allowing text selection would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Since I control the content of my app, I was able to disable press-hold of images by using the following css: `-webkit-touch-callout: none;`  So my remaining problem is just to disallow drag interactions out of the app from the `WKWebView`.

**UPDATE 2**
Similarly, I was able to use `-webkit-user-drag: none;` to disable dragging of links, but it would still be useful to know a non-css fix for what seems to me like an Apple bug.

Answer (score 3):

This may be related to a known Webkit bug that is presumably already fixed (as of this writing):

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210191

Comment: That indeed looks exactly like my bug. Thanks.

Comment: Do we know when these get fixed?

Comment: I do not. I presume that is up the sole discretion and prioritization of Apple.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem, and this is how I solved it.

```
wkwebview.UIDelegate = self;
```

...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WKWebView *)webView shouldPreviewElement:(WKPreviewElementInfo *)elementInfo API_AVAILABLE(ios(10.0)) {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I tried that, but I can't be sure. Since that API is deprecated, I was using the modern replacement `webView(_:contextMenuConfigurationForElement:completionHandler:)`, which I would have thought would have equivalent behavior.  I'll have to give this a try and see if it would be an alternate solution to the problem.

Comment: @JonBrooks Did you get it to work with `webView(_:contextMenuConfigurationForElement:completionHandler:)` ?