# SwiftUI WKWebView disable link interactions

Tags: ios, swiftui, webkit, wkwebview

I am looking for a way to disable a user interacting with links and images in SwiftUI using WKWebView.  I have tried various ways but none have worked, and I have seen and tried the following post but nothing worked:

[WKWebview allowsLinkPreview to false breaks text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106626/wkwebview-allowslinkpreview-to-false-breaks-text-selection)

[WKWebview: Disable interaction and clicks on links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366947/wkwebview-disable-interaction-and-clicks-on-links)

I am displaying a website that I have permission to display but due to its abnormal HTML structure it makes it hard to display the context, so I decided to try disabling user interactions with links.  I do still want user interactions enabled so the user can scroll through the calendar presented to them, but not be able to click on links.  If you have any suggestion I am open to them.

Here is my code:

```
struct CalanderWeb : UIViewRepresentable {

    @State var request: URLRequest

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {

        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        uiView.isOpaque = false
        uiView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false

        uiView.load(request)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> CalanderWeb.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }


    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        let parent: CalanderWeb

        init(_ parent: CalanderWeb) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {

        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        }
    }

}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is correct delegate callback

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

depending of used HTML, probably also might be disabled `.formSubmitted`, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override the method `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` in `WKNavigationDelegate` and provide `.cancel` in the completion block parameter `decisionHandler`. Here is the sample code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    decisionHandler(.cancel)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I added this to my Coordinator (I will update the above code with that), but it does not allow me to override that.  Do you have any ideas as to why?

Comment: You will have to set the `WKWebView`'s `navigationDelegate` to the coordinator.

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot to do that.  You also have to make sure .allow is set as well like Asperi's asnwer or else it does not load.